SPARK delimiter is not applying to data
I'm trying to use delimiter on my CSV file using PySpark but it's not working properly.
It's a file that has information about employees.
The header and the following data look like this (I cannot show all of them because they are real information).

The data appears like this when I use show df_pyspark.show():

I searched on Stack and I found this:
Pyspark reading csv delimiter not parsed for some data

However, in my file, there are no quotation marks or any other punctuation marks.
Can anybody help?
Follows my code:
df_pyspark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Pratica').getOrCreate()

df_pyspark = spark.read.csv('/funcionarios/funcionarios.csv')

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType, DoubleType

schema = StructType([
StructField('Nome do funcionário', StringType(), True),
StructField('CPF', StringType(), True),
StructField('RG', StringType(), True),
StructField('Data de Nascimento', DateType(), True),
StructField('Data de admissão', StringType(), True),
StructField('Departamento', StringType(), True),
StructField('Função', StringType(), True)
])

import pyspark.sql.types

df_pyspark.printSchema() 
df_pyspark.show()

df_pyspark = (
   spark.read.
    format("csv").
    schema(schema)
    .option("header", True)
    .option("charset", "ISO-8859-1") #decodificação do alfabeto latino
    .option('inferSchema',True)
    .option('delimiter',';')
    .load('/funcionarios/funcionarios.csv')
    )


Could you please clarify what is your input(you can just provide some mock data)expected output and what output you are getting, this will help in comparing and debugging.
Side note : you can copy the data in a notepad and check for any hidden character which might be causing issue with special character.
One more thing you can check with trying different encoding,UTF-8 and see if that works.

The data looks like this:
roberto;11111111111;11111111111111111111;06/04/2000;05/04/2023;RECEPÇÃO PRINCIPAL;ASSISTENTE DE ATENDIMENTO AO CLIENTE I
I expected it to be split into columns like this:
roberto | 11111111111 | 11111111111111111111 | 06/04/2000 | 05/04/2023 | RECEPÇÃO PRINCIPAL | ASSISTENTE DE ATENDIMENTO AO CLIENTE I
I’ve tried a few things, but nothing changed.
It’s probably an issue with the source file I’m downloading.
